# Overloading functions only for char* and strings

Tags: c++, overloading, default-parameters

I'm making some functions to save and load my values:

They are these two:

```
void safeFile(string &set_name) const;
void loadFile(string &set_name);
```

The problem here is that I also want them to work for char* so I overloaded them like this:

```
void safeFile(string &set_name) const;
void loadFile(string &set_name);   
void safeFile(char* set_name) const;
void loadFile(char* set_name);
```

In the cpp file:

```
void myclass::loadFile(string &set_name)
{
   ...
}
/* loadFile */


void myclass::safeFile(string &set_name)
{
   ...
}
/* safeFile*/


void myclass::loadFile(char *set_name)
{
    string mystring(set_name);
    loadFile(mystring);
}
/* loadFile */


void myclass::safeFile(char *set_name) const
{
    string mystring(set_name);
    safeFile(mystring);
}
/* safeFile*/
```

Is there any better or other way I should do it ? Thanks

Comment: Barry gave you a solution, but you may want to read more about conversions [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

Comment: This will be very useful, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't add the overload for `char*`. `saveFile` and `loadFile` should simply take their arguments as `const std::string&`.

If you had:

```
void saveFile(std::string const& );
```

You could call it with both:

```
obj.saveFile("file.txt");
obj.saveFile(std::string("file.txt"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im trying to do this but now I have an issue. If I use `obj.saveFile("file.txt")` I get the error `"No matching function for call to myclass::saveFile(const char [])`. I can see the compiler is saving the "file.txt" as a const char*. How can I force it to be a string? (<string> is included in the file). I have also tried string("file.txt"), but the error now is `No match function for call myclass::saveFile(std::string). Candidates are myclass::saveFile(std::string&)`. Why can't it use the returned value of the string constructor as a reference ?. Thanks

Comment: @Ediolot Not `saveFile(std::string&)`, `saveFile(const std::string&)`. The `const` is important! You cannot take a non-const reference to something of the wrong type. You *can* construct a const reference though.

Comment: You are right, I was making a mess with "const", but I was able to understand it at last. Thanks